# Failed to group the data by row in CSV file with Java

Tags: java, functional-programming

Any clue why does there is an error on line[1] (cannot find symbol line)? I would like to group data based on row number 1 in the CSV file, but I failed to do so.

```java
private final static String COMMA_DELIMITER = ",";
     public List<List<String>> readCSVFile() throws IOException{
          List<List<String>> result = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("D:\\APLC\\time_series_covid19_confirmed_global.csv"))
                                         .stream()
                                         .skip(1)
                                         .map(line -> Arrays.asList(line.split(COMMA_DELIMITER)))
                                         .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(line[1]).toList()); 
          return result; 
     }
}
```

Sample Output:
FROM:
| Country| 20/06/2021| 21/06/2021 |
|:---- |:------:| -----:|
| Malaysia| 1 | 2 |
| Malaysia| 1 | 2 |
| Malaysia| 1 | 2 |

TO:
| Country| 20/06/2021| 21/06/2021 |
|:---- |:------:| -----:|
| Malaysia| 3 | 6 |

Comment: Do you mean group by column 1? Would you please share sample input and expected output?

Comment: For instance, there is multiple column that have the same value(eg: Malaysia), but they are under one row named "Country". Therefore, I would like to combine all data in one column named "Malaysia".

Comment: Got it. I think you are interchanging rows and columns. Each line of your CSV is a row and each command separated value in a row is a column. I assume you would like to group data by column `Country` and that happens to be the first column. Again, request you edit the question to share sample input and output.

Comment: I strongly suggest that you use a CSV parser instead. If any of the field values contains the delimiter character, your code will break.

Comment: What error do you get? A compile time error, or a runtime error? Please paste the error you get.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things:

1. While grouping you are referring to `line[1]` incorrectly. `line` variable can't be accessed there.
2. `Collectors.groupingBy(Function, Collector)` takes a function and collector
3. When grouping is done the result will be a `Map` with grouping value as the key in the `Map` (in this case String). Hence the result type has to be changed from `List<List<String>>` to `Map<String, List<List<String>>>`

Here is the running example code:

```java
package org.openapex.samples.misc.parse.csv;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class ReadAndGroup70224600 {
    private final static String COMMA_DELIMITER = ",";
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        readCSVFile("/resource/population.csv");
    }

    public static Map<String, List<List<String>>> readCSVFile(String file) throws IOException {
        Map<String, List<List<String>>> result = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(file))
                .stream()
                .skip(1)
                .map(line -> Arrays.asList(line.split(COMMA_DELIMITER)))
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(value -> value.get(0), Collectors.toList()));
        System.out.println(result);
        return result;
    }
}
```

With the following input:

```
country,city,population
USA,San Francisco,20000
USA,NewYork City,60000
Australia,Sydney,25000
Australia,Melbourne,22000
USA,Boston,40000
England,London,70000
```

It produces the following output:

```
{USA=[[USA, San Francisco, 20000], [USA, NewYork City, 60000], [USA, Boston, 40000]], England=[[England, London, 70000]], Australia=[[Australia, Sydney, 25000], [Australia, Melbourne, 22000]]}
```